# Deleting Flag requests

Tags: feature-request, flagging

Is it possible to delete a flag requests? I accidently fat fingered my request. I know there are moderator's blowing steam right now. I'd like that to be a feature request.

Comment: I'm so angry right now! >_<

Comment: see?!? no need for admin torture!

Comment: Actually, this isn't a big deal really. We have to validate the merit of flags all the time so we would just decline it.

Comment: Ok thanks, Kit.

Comment: You're welcome. Keep those (correct) flags coming! :)